# Comparing dates in pandas timestamp to datetime,date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `df`. The dataframe is read from an excel. The column `shortdate` in the dataframe contains the dates. What I am trying to do is to obtain last weeks date, and then pull all the rows in the `df` that are between last weeks date and todays date.
The problem is that the dates in the `df` and the dates in the excel file are different formats so I cant compare them properly. one is a time stamp and one is a type date.

In the case below I was just testing with a known value in the `df` to see if it works. but it doesn't work. it returns an empty `df` because the values do not exist in the `shortdate` column.

**Main.py**

```
todays_date = datetime.today().date() #todays date
date_of_last_week = todays_date - timedelta(days=7) #this is last weeks date

print('last weeks date :', date_of_last_week)
print('last weeks type is :', type(date_of_last_week))
entry_1000 = df['shortdate'][1000]
print('1000 entry date is:',entry_1000)
print('1000 entry type is:', type(entry_1000))
print('1000 entry date just date is:',entry_1000.date())
print('1000 entry just date type is:', type(entry_1000.date()))

just_date = entry_1000.date()
print(df_eb.loc[df['shortdate'] == just_date])
```

**Results:**

```
last weeks date : 2021-10-15
last weeks type is : <class 'datetime.date'>
1000 entry date is: 2020-03-28 00:00:00
1000 entry type is: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
1000 entry date just date is: 2020-03-28
1000 entry just date type is: <class 'datetime.date'>
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [record, old record, Status, shortdate]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `shortdate` column to `datetime` data-type using below code

```
df.shortdate = df.shortdate.apply(lambda x: x.date())
```

Comment: thank you it worked